# Rewriting a polar equasion as parametric to a third variable.

Tags: physics, parametric

Say I have a very simple polar equation $r=\sin(2\theta)$ and I want to somehow transform/rewrite it into a pair of parametric equations where they both dependent on a third factor $x$ such that the distance traversed by point $(r,\theta)$ is linearly related to the variable $x$. How would I do so and how can I apply it to more complex polar equations (generalize)?

#### Background

I am building a Sisyphus table where there is a motor turning an arm (this is the $\theta$ motor). On the arm is a linear actuator that traverses from 0 to 1 ($r$ motor). The linear actuator has a magnet that moves a ball bearing across a layer of sand and leaves an indent in the sand as it moves through. The hardware and firmware is figured out, all I need is a script that can feed the $\theta$ and $r$ to the firmware. I would like the ball bearing to be moving at a constant speed instead of at a variable speed that is somewhat related to the current radius. Thus far, I have figured out that I have to somehow compensate for the radius along the curve but overall I am pretty lost.

Comment: Re-parametrize the curve $\theta\mapsto\gamma(\theta)=(r(\theta)\cos\theta,r(\theta)\sin\theta)$ with new parameter being its arc-length: $s:=\int_0^\theta\|\dot\gamma(t)\|\,dt\,.$ You will see that the speed of $\gamma$ w.r.t. $s$ is constant.

Comment: @KurtG. how would I go about doing this? Detail instructions or pointer to a resource would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To learn this in the best way you should at least make the minimal effort to calculate $s$ in your example. If you prefer the second best method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4674041/949989) is a related post.